# Why i can't get value from useContext?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Why i can't get value from useContext ?

sorry I update already

*components/useContext/index.js*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Article from "./article";
import status from "./status";
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export const articleContext = createContext();
const App = () => {
  const article = "chanheng";
  return (
    <div>
      <articleContext.Provider value={article}>
        {console.log(article)}
        <Article />
      </articleContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*components/useContext/article.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import articleContext from "./index";
const Article = () => {
  const article = useContext(articleContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{`Article title is: ${article}`}</h3>
      {console.log(article)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Article;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrKQs.png)

Comment: Why does `components/useContext/index.js` load `./index`? And the two code sections look the same apart from a new line?

Comment: Can you share the `articleContext` file ??

Comment: sorry, i already update my answer for double file

Comment: I feel it is working perfectly fine. https://playcode.io/929918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, you are importing articleContext in wrong way, that's why it doesn't recognize the context as well.
Since you are exporting it as ***export const*** you have to import it as the following :

Wrong:

```
import articleContext from "./index";
```

Correct:

```
import { articleContext } from "./index";
```